# php imagick not working, does it need to be decoded?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I'm just learning imagick and just want to see it work. My basic usage is going to be creating thumbnails and rendering .ai & .psd files.

My phpinfo() shows imagemagick installed.

I have this code that I got from http://valokuva.org/?cat=1 :

```
    /* Create new object */
$im = new Imagick();

/* Create new checkerboard pattern */
$im->newPseudoImage(100, 100, "pattern:checkerboard");

/* Set the image format to png */
$im->setImageFormat('png');

/* Fill background area with transparent */
$im->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);

/* Activate matte */
$im->setImageMatte(true);

/* Control points for the distortion */
$controlPoints = array( 10, 10,
                        10, 5,

                        10, $im->getImageHeight() - 20,
                        10, $im->getImageHeight() - 5,

                        $im->getImageWidth() - 10, 10,
                        $im->getImageWidth() - 10, 20,

                        $im->getImageWidth() - 10, $im->getImageHeight() - 10,
                        $im->getImageWidth() - 10, $im->getImageHeight() - 30);

/* Perform the distortion */ 
$im->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $controlPoints, true);

/* Ouput the image */   
//header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $im;
```

now the code as is just prints characters on the screen like:

�PNG  IHDRo�*��ybKGD����9�  oFFs��������^�� pHYsHHF�k>3CIDATx���w�U���̽[�H!��   ��л(�BQ@�(E� ���" J�NQA�4)�{�=�R�e˽3�Ϭ$!�l�%�o~��Mٝ{��y�������d��^'��I&7��}f���[��(�,���]lЍ���<�*Cog�&��������L���������d'L��a'���<��<�;C`Fa.䗋

if I un-comment  the second to last line it just takes me to a broken image.

Do i need to do something else? maybe decode and save file? Maybe i'm doing this wrong.

Comment: tested that code, works, maybe you imagick installation is not ok.

Comment: Why have you commented out the header?  That output indicates no header.

Comment: Or rather the browser misinterpreting the output as text.  Have you got anything else outputting to the browser, particularly in front of the image, whitespace or anything.

Comment: I commented out the header as a test, because all it returns is a broken image.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. I was doing other things in that file that was outputting text to the browser. once I put it into a independent file it worked.

Comment: you should also make sure you send a `header()` with the appropriate mime type, to ensure that the browser recognises the file type.

Comment: @JasonSpick - don't forget to add a ticked solution below, so this question is removed from the no-answers lists `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Double check your php file doesn't contain [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).